# Comparing Staggered Dates

Tags: excel, date, match, lookup

I have two small tables: one of values that the stock market returned, and the other of the values my trades returned (All of the data is made up).

As you can see, there was not a trade on every day. I am trying to create a table like the third one seen that matches the date in column F to the date in column C and returns the corresponding return. Basically I want to return the second table into the third.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried to use the `FIND`, `CELL`, `INDEX`, etc., but as I am pretty new to Excel, I am not sure I am using them quite right.

Answer (score 1):

in cell `H3` of your example, enter formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,$C$3:$D$11,2,FALSE)
```

...and the copy or "fill" that formula down to the end of your data (`H7`).

---

Note that this will return an error if the date does not exist in the target range.

You can suppress the error by instead using:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F3,$C$3:$D$11,2,FALSE),"")
```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**VLOOKUP Function** *(with video tutorial)*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
- Office.com : [**IFERROR Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)
- mbaExcel : [*Tutorial:* **How to Decide Which Excel Lookup Formula to Use**](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/tutorial-how-to-decide-which-excel-lookup-formula-to-use/)